# Disable Sentry reporting when using djangos `manage.py shell`

Tags: python, django, sentry

I am using sentry to report errors ocurring in my django app.

Is there a way to disable sentry error reporting when using a command like

`python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ignoring some or all types of exceptions in Sentry you can use 
`ignore_exceptions` option for `RAVEN_CONFIG` in your `settings.py` file.
`ignore_exceptions` accepts a list of Exception Classes or String Paths. 
You can read more about ignoring exceptions in Sentry docs here: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/advanced/

To ignore all exceptions, you can pass `['*']` to `ignore_exceptions`, but you want to do this only when the django process has been started with the mentioned command in question, which could be known from `sys.argv`. So, your desired outcome could be achieved by adding following codes to your django `settings.py` file:

```
import sys
SHOULD_IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS = " ".join(sys.argv).endswith("run python manage.py shell")

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': '...',
    'ignore_exceptions': ['*'] if SHOULD_IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS else [],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented but definetly stable setting for that:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'install_sys_hook': False
}
```